# Redirect with 301 but Keep Same URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to have a 301 redirect and keep the original URL?  Like in the example below:

```
Redirect 301 /rsvp1 http://www.tourspain.com/rsvp1.html
```

I want the have /rsvp1 redirect to the page and still have /rsvp1 in the URL window

Answer (score 1):

> I want the have /rsvp1 redirect to the page and still have /rsvp1 in
>   the URL window

You can do that without a Redirect using Content negotation - [MultiViews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

In .htaccess you can put at the top

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Or you can do it with `mod_rewrite` but not `mod_alias` (redirect)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^rsvp1/?$ /rsvp1.html [L]
```